# Запретить вывод страницы PHP cURL

Tags: curl, php

Всем привет! Отправляю POST-запрос посредством cURL PHP, нигде не указываю вывод страницы, но она все равно выводится. Как сделать так, чтобы результата не было видно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разобрался! Задал параметр **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER**:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```